Sequelize finder function apply default value instead of reading response
I'm having an issue where when I query data from the DB it's generating a random UUID for my record instead of using the proper one.
Say I have the following table
import { 
  Column, 
  DataType, 
  Default, 
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Table, 
  IsLowercase,
  Unique
} from 'sequelize-typescript'

@Table({ underscored: true, paranoid: true, timestamps: true })
export abstract class BaseModel<T> extends Model<T> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  id: string

  @Column
  readonly createdAt: Date

  @Column
  readonly updatedAt: Date

  @Column
  readonly deletedAt: Date

  constructor(input?: any) {
    super()
    if (input) {
      Object.assign(this, input)
   }
  }
}


@Table
export default class Foo extends BaseModel<Tag> {
  @Unique
  @IsLowercase
  @Column(DataType.STRING(32))
  name: string

  toJSON(): object {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      updatedAt: this.updatedAt,
    }
  }
}

Then creating a and finding an object returns
const f = await Foo.findAll();
console.log("created id", f.id);
// => created id cda0f763-2384-4116-970d-f6418678787c
const foundFoo= await Foo.findOne();
console.log("found id", foundFoo.id);
// => found id 6ae277c7-1797-4bfa-a9dd-c893d004a151

I now the ID is being stored and even being requested correctly because if I do
const f = await Foo.findAll();
console.log("created id", f.id);
// => created id cda0f763-2384-4116-970d-f6418678787c
const foundFoo= await Foo.findOne({ raw: true });
console.log("found id", foundFoo.id);
// => found id cda0f763-2384-4116-970d-f6418678787c

but now I have a plain object without any of the Sequelize methods I need. Why is this happening?
I'm running node.js v18.18.2, sequelize ^6.37.1, sequelize-typescript: ^2.1.3 on Linux

I think this is a case of your id field shadowing sequelizes's getter & setter and should be removed. Using your sample model, you should create it this way:
@Table({ underscored: true, paranoid: true, timestamps: true })
export abstract class BaseModel<T> extends Model<T> {
  /* I have removed the id field. */

  @Column
  readonly createdAt: Date

  @Column
  readonly updatedAt: Date

  @Column
  readonly deletedAt: Date

  constructor(input?: any) {
    super()
    if (input) {
      Object.assign(this, input)
   }
  }
}

@Table
export default class Foo extends BaseModel<Tag> {
  @Unique
  @IsLowercase
  @Column(DataType.STRING(32))
  name: string

  toJSON(): object {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      updatedAt: this.updatedAt,
    }
  }
}

Foo.init(
  {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 // Or DataTypes.UUIDV1
    },
  },
  { sequelize },
);

If you really want that removed field, use a different name that isn't id.

If i drop id from baseModel  then .sync() assumes SERIAL. So I have to define @Table and init for every column for every table within my project. Seems very duplicative. Especially if I create migration files which is recommended by the docs, so I'd have to define every model 3 times.  Is this the only way?

The docs do indicate that it should not be declared in the class caveat-with-public-class-fields.  I'll have to ask a different question about setting the default id type with the implicit id column which is defined in the migration file. Typescript gives me an error when I call Foo.init and only define the id.
